# Application is opening on chrome but speech to text is not working on Mobile google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, mobile-chrome

I have created a web application(https) and it uses speech to text and text to speech using the google chrome browser. **The application is working well on laptop and desktop google chrome browsers but when I open the application on mobile...although the text to speech is working...speech to text part is not working, it is not taking my speech input**.

I am wondering, why is it happening when the application is working all well on laptop/desktop chrome but it is not working on mobile chrome. How to make this work on mobile chrome?

I have used both the functions: mediadevices.getusermedia() and navigator.getusermedia() and tried out but it is not working out on mobile chrome

**Expected**: It takes my voice input and shows it as text on the mobile browser

**Current**: It is not taking voice as input on mobile browser

Comment: It should be a permission issue probably. Are you trying on Android?

Comment: I tried on both Android and iOS.